# Design a class named Account and test it

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Okay so I'm having a problem with writing this code and the test code used for is and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work.

The assignment in question says: Design a class named Account that contains:

■ A private int data field named id for the account.

■ A private float data field named balance for the account.

■ A private float data field named annualInterestRate that stores the current
interest rate.

■ A constructor that creates an account with the specified id (default 0), initial
balance (default 100), and annual interest rate (default 0).

■ The accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.

■ A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly
interest rate.

■ A method named getMonthlyInterest() that returns the monthly interest.

■ A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the
account.

■ A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account.

(Hint: The method getMonthlyInterest() is to return the monthly interest amount, not
the interest rate. Use this formula to calculate the monthly interest: balance *
monthlyInterestRate. monthlyInterestRate is annualInterestRate
/ 12. Note that annualInterestRate is a percent (like 4.5%). You need to
divide it by 100.)

Write a test program that creates an Account object with an account id of 1122, a
balance of $20,000, and an annual interest rate of 4.5%. Use the withdraw
method to withdraw $2,500, use the deposit method to deposit $3,000, and print
the id, balance, monthly interest rate, and monthly interest.

this is the code I have so far for the class:

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self, accountid = 0, initialbalance = 100, annualInterestrate = 0):
        self.accountid = accountid
        self.initalbalance = initialbalance
        self.annualInterestrate = annualInterestrate

    def balance(self):
        return float(self.balance)

    def id(self):
        return int(self.id)

    def annualInterestrate(self):
        return float(self.annaulInterestrate)

    def getid(self):
        return self.id

    def setbalance(self):
        return self.setbalance 

    def getannualInterestrate(self):
        return self.annualInterestrate

    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return self.annualInterestrate / 100

    def withdraw(self):
        amount = 28
        if self.balance>=amount: 
            self.balance-=amount 

    def deposit(self): 
        amount =  45
        self.balance += amount 

    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return  balance * monthlyInterestRate. monthlyInterestRate is annualInterestRate / 12
```

ignore the numbers 45 and 28 I just put them there as place holders.

this is what I have for the test program (it's incomplete at the moment since I'm lost):

```
from Account import Account

def main():
    account1 = Account()
    print("Account id # is", account1.getid)


    print("Beginning Balance: ", account1.setbalance)
    print("Monthly Interest Rate: ", account1.getMonthlyInterestRate())
    print("Monthly Interest: ", account1.getMonthlyInterest())

main()
```

I have no idea what I'm doing. If anyone has an idea on what I'm supposed to do please help.

I'm trying to figure out how I information into the class (or the test program if that's what's required) and have it output something like:

Account id # is, 1122

Beginning Balance: whatever the balance is after a withdraw and/or deposit

Monthly Interest rate: whatever all the math leads to.

Monthly Interest: again, whatever all the math leads to

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing in some information when you create the account?  `Account(id=1122, initialbalance=20000, annualInterestrate=0.045)`?

Comment: And it generally helps to state what you expected and what you actually got as results.  Otherwise, it's difficult to know what "wrong" means. :-)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Right sorry, regarding the lack of information I'm trying to figure out where I should insert that info at. Specifically how do I get that information into the class (or the test program if that's what's required) and have it out put something like:

Account id # is, 1122

Beginning Balance: *whatever the balance is after a withdraw and/or deposit*

Monthly Interest rate: *whatever all the math leads to.*

Monthly Interest: *again, whatever all the math leads to.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start talking about the functionality of the class, I will talk about the class design.

> ■ A private int data field named id for the account.
>
> ■ A private float data field named balance for the account.
>
> ■ A private float data field named annualInterestRate that stores the current interest rate.

You may have not noticed it, but you were actually making your data field public. Consider the following code:

```py
class Account:
   id = 2
```

The id can be accessed from anywhere else in the code, for example (Do notice that this isn't using an instance of the class):

```py
print(Account.id)
```

Continuing with this example, we can have an instance have a different value of id.

```py
class account:
  id = 2
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = 4

print(account.id)
foo = account()
print(foo.id)
```

This id can still be accessed from outside the instance of the class, it is still public. To make it private, we add a __ before the variable. Now we should get an error when trying to access the instance's id, but not when a function access's the id.

```py
class account:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__id = 4

  def getId(self):
    return self.__id

foo = account()
print(foo.getId())
print(foo.__id) # Will produce an error
```

If you are still confused at this point, I would suggest reading about "access specifiers" and "encapsulation". It's fine if you read it in a different language like Java or C++, it is the exact same concept.

Also, I would cast `accountid` into an int and `initialbalance` and `annualInterestRate` into floats in your constructor, so you don't have to cast in your other "getter" methods (the ones just returning the variables). They should be saved as those data types anyways, since those are the requirements.

The next bullet points state that (skipping the constructor one, you got that one):

> ■ The accessor and mutator methods for id, balance, and annualInterestRate.
>
> ■ A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate.
>
> ■ A method named getMonthlyInterest() that returns the monthly interest.
>
> ■ A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account.
>
> ■ A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account.

Now that the class design is finished, we need to work on the class function. We will reduce the code in the "getter" (accessor) methods by just returning the variable, since it is already the correct data type. Now we just need to make the "setter" (mutator) methods, which will change the values. Looking at your code, I don't think that you have a full understanding of getter and setter methods, and I will describe them breifly.

A getter method just returns a class variable that is otherwise hidden (because it's private)

A setter method just changes the value of a class variable. You need to do this through a method because the variable is private. We will use a parameter for the setter methods, and it won't return anything.

The class should now look something like this

```py
'''
Random Project
--------------
This is what I use for testing things
'''
class account:
  # Constructor
  def __init__(self, id = 0, balance = 100.0, annualInterestRate = 0.0):
    self.__id = int(id)
    self.__balance = float(balance)
    self.__annualInterestRate = float(annualInterestRate)

  # Getters (Accessors)
  def getId(self):
    return self.__id

  def getBalance(self):
    return self.__balance

  def getAnnualInterestRate(self):
    return self.__annualInterestRate

  # Setters (Mutators)
  '''
  Notice that they are the exact
  same as the constructor, just
  that they edit the variables
  individually
  '''
  def setId(self, id):
    self.__id = int(id)

  def setBalance(self, balance):
    self.__balance = float(balance)

  def setAnnualInterestRate(self, annualInterestRate):
    self.__annualInterestRate = float(annualInterestRate)
```

The last bullet points are:

> ■ A method named getMonthlyInterestRate() that returns the monthly interest rate.
>
> ■ A method named getMonthlyInterest() that returns the monthly interest.
>
> ■ A method named withdraw that withdraws a specified amount from the account.
>
> ■ A method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the account.

Your withdraw and deposit functions are fine, but you should really be using parameters instead

```py
def withdraw(self, amount):
   self.__balance -= amount

def deposit(self, amount):
   self.__balance += amount
```

Your get monthlyInterestRate() method should be / 12, and finally, monthlyInterestRate is not defined in the scope of getMonthlyInterest(). Replace it with self.getMonthlyInterestRate(). When testing, make sure you initialize your Account object with parameters

Finally, here is the entire class code:

```py
class account:
  # Constructor
  def __init__(self, id = 0, balance = 100.0, annualInterestRate = 0.0):
    self.__id = int(id)
    self.__balance = float(balance)
    self.__annualInterestRate = float(annualInterestRate)

  # Getters (Accessors)
  def getId(self):
    return self.__id

  def getBalance(self):
    return self.__balance

  def getAnnualInterestRate(self):
    return self.__annualInterestRate

  # Setters (Mutators)
  '''
  Notice that they are the exact
  same as the constructor, just
  that they edit the variables
  individually
  '''
  def setId(self, id):
    self.__id = int(id)

  def setBalance(self, balance):
    self.__balance = float(balance)

  def setAnnualInterestRate(self, annualInterestRate):
    self.__annualInterestRate = float(annualInterestRate)

  # Calculating functions
  def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
    return self.__annualInterestRate / 12

  def getMonthlyInterest(self):
    return self.__balance * self.getMonthlyInterestRate()
```

I think you should do a little bit more research on functions, how you can use them to simplify your code, class access specifiers, so you can understand the principle of least privilege. I know that this probably makes no sense right now, but with a few google searches and playing around with some code, it'll all make sense.